# Invalid syntax error for loop

Tags: python

I get the error "Invalid syntax" at the second line in my script:

```
def pointsInsideTriangles(points,triangles): 
    for (P in points):
        for (t in triangles):
            if isInsideTriangle(P,t[0],t[1],t[2]):
                print("Point " + str(P) + " is inside triangle " + str(t))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, that is invalid syntax in Python. You don't use parentheses in a for statement.

Answer (score 2):

As described in the documentation, [`for`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#for) loop has the following syntax:

```
for_stmt ::=  "for" target_list "in" expression_list ":" suite
              ["else" ":" suite]
```

So, you should remove parenthesis after the `for` keyword